# how to display selected value from DB to multiselect dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a multiselect dropdown, the value for the dropdown is coming from the database. how to populate the multiselect dropdown with more than one selected value.

my viewbag in controller

```
var app_dependent = (from ao in db.mas_app_dependent
                     where ao.app_key == id   // id is app_key(PK) value=1
                     select ao.app_dependent__key).ToList();
 ViewBag.app_key = new SelectList(db.mas_apps, "app_key", "app_name", app_dependent);
```

my view in index.cshtml page

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label id="ownerbiz" class="control-label col-md-2">Dependent Application</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("app_key", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control e1", @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Select / Search here!" })
  </div>
```

my db.mas_apps table value

```
  app_key(PK)  app_name
        1        CRTS
        2        CITRIX
        12       Hiport
        15       Frig
```

my db.mas_app_dependent values for the variable app_dependent

```
dep_key(PK) app_key dependent_app_key
1           1         2 
12          1         12
```

Comment: please suggest me how to pass more than one value to the view bag select list,

Comment: Do you want to show multiples columns as selected value or you want to pass list of selectlist ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad  no, the mas_app_depepedent is the table used to save the value from the multiselect dropdown, if we select value in dropdown it will be save in the table and retrival is based from the table it gives the value which are selected in  the dropdown while in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller

```
var dependent = (from ad in db.mas_app_dependent
                                 where ad.app_key == id && ad.inactive==true
                                 select ad.dependent_app_key).ToArray();
 ViewBag.app_key = new MultiSelectList(db.mas_apps, "app_key", "app_name", dependent);-----viewbag for dropdown
```

in view

```
@Html.DropDownList("app_key", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control e1", @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Select / Search here!", id="dependent" })
```

create an hidden element

```
            @Html.Hidden("hdn_dependent")
```

and we can get the values from the selected dropdown by creating an id to the dropdown. and use jquery to fecth the selectted values in the multiselect dropdown

```
    var dep = $('#dependent').val().toString();    
    $("#hdn_dependent").val(dep);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have bind  bootstrap multiselect with database value For state  by using

In the Controller Action Menthod

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult ManageShippers()
{
  var stateList = db.states.ToList(); 
  ViewBag.State = new SelectList(stateList, "StateId", "StateName");
}
```

Inside the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlMultiSelectState", ViewBag.State as SelectList, new { @id = "ddlMultiSelectState", Name = "Select State", @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Its works.

Comment: OP asking how to preselect multiple values when the view is rendered. Which this does not do!

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use a view model with properties for the selected values and for the option collection

```
public class MyVM
{
  public int[] SelectedValues { get; set; }
  public SelectList AllValues { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
var app_dependent = (from ao in db.mas_app_dependent
                     where ao.app_key == id  // id is app_key(PK) value=1
                     select ao.app_dependent__key).ToArray();
MyVM model = new MyVM();
model.SelectedValues  = app_dependent;
model.AllValues = new SelectList(db.mas_apps, "app_key", "app_name");
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, Model.AllValues, new { @class = "form-control e1" })
```

Note `ListBoxFor()` add the `multiple="multiple" attribute

If `SelectedValues` contains (say) `[2, 12]`, then the 2nd and 4th options will be selected when the view is rendered.

Comment: i can't able to assign the value model.SelectedValues=app_dependent;

Comment: Isn't the value of `app_dependent` an array of `int`? - try `ToArray()` instad of `ToList()` on you query (or change the property to `public List<int> SelectedValues { get; set; }`

Comment: cant able to assign in public SelectList AllValues { get; set; }                               it shows error like The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: You dont! Look at my code - you assign `app_dependent ` to `SelectedValues`. `AllValues` is the `SelectList`